# Set cookie in Safari ios does'nt work in Nuxt SSR

Tags: vue.js, cookies, nuxt.js, token, server-side-rendering

I try to set my token in the cookies. It works fine on all browsers EXCEPT Safari ios.

I specify that I am on Nuxt in SSR. I saw that I could go through VuexPersist but I lose the SSR and it's not the idea.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Are the calls cross-domain, like to `api.example.com` on `example.com`? If so, iOS 14 blocked cross-domain cookies by default to impede tracking.

Comment: We don't have any cross-domain calls (example.com => example.com/api)